# Android Studio adding a file to GitHub

Tags: android, github

I am currently coding a project in Android Studio and uploading all my code to GitHub via Android Studio. However, I am having trouble adding an xml file to the commit. When I commit and push, the file does not get pushed. It is glowing red in the file sidebar. How can I commit this file so I can push it to GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the file, go to "Git", and click "+ add".